# Coreplot with Monotouch: date as x axis labels

Tags: xamarin.ios, core-plot

I want to draw a plot using dates as labels for the x axis, but I don´t see how to do it. I have seen a few examples with Objective-C but I have not been able to translate it. Which is the way to go?